# How to use multiple post_type in WP_Query?

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, posts

I have created custom fields, and am using `WP_Query` to output them. I have a "visibility section" and "credibility section", with custom post types for each set up in the ACF plugin. My visibility section is working perfectly, but I need to figure out how to add my credibility post type to the array argument, so that I can output my posts in that bottom section. I don't think I can just add another post_type => 'credibility_section' to it...

```
<?php
  $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'visibility_section'
    //Can I add 'post_type' => 'credibility_section' here?
  );

  $query = new WP_Query( $args );
?>

<section class="row visibility-content"><!-- Start visibility section -->
  <div class="container">
    <h3 class="text-xs-center m-b-3">Visibility</h3>
    <div class="col-md-6">
    <?php if ( $query->have_posts() ) : while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>
      <p><?php the_field( 'visibility_left_column' ); ?></p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <?php if( get_field( 'visibility_image' ) ): ?>
            <img src="<?php the_field( 'visibility_image'); ?>" />
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <p><?php the_field( 'visibility_bottom' ); ?></p>
    </div>
  <?php endwhile; endif; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
  </div>
</section>

<section class="row cred-content"><!-- Start Credibility section -->
  <div class="container">
    <h3 class="text-xs-center m-b-3">Credibility</h3>
    <div class="col-md-12">

    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> You can pass multiple `post_type` using **array** in `WP_Query` argument.

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => array( 'visibility_section', 'credibility_section')
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

---

Reference:

- [WP_Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Post_.26_Page_Parameters)