# Building a custom WP_Query with two post types - JSON

Tags: json, wordpress

In my WordPress post carousel widget I have the ability to create a custom query. And I need it to display items from two post types: news, articles.

But I do not get how the "AND" operator works for post types.

So far I got this

```
{"post_type":"articles","post_status":"publish","order":"DESC","orderby":"date"}
```

which returns "Articles" just fine. How can I include "News" as well in the same carousel?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use multiple post\_type in WP\_Query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39819680/how-to-use-multiple-post-type-in-wp-query) eg `post_type` supports an array for multiple values

Comment: No, I'm not looking for PHP solution.

Comment: It's the exact same answer in JSON: just use an array

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution, I just needed to use an array

```
{
"post_type": [
"articles", "news"
],
"post_status":"publish",
"order":"DESC",
"orderby":"date"
}
```